# How do i edit the favicon in the Browsable API in Django REST framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to edit the favicon of the Browsable API. 
Is it possible to do that by overriding api.html in templates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved by adding the following block in api.html

```
{% block style %}
{{ block.super }}
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="xxxx.png" />
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3):

To expand on [Arun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46878125/4794), you can set the favicon by [customizing the browsable API](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api/#customizing). That means you create a copy of `api.html` in your app, and then add a link to your favicon.

In this example, I have the following files:

- `my_project`

  - `my_app`

    - `static`

      - `favicon.png`
    - `templates`

      - `rest_framework`

        - `api.html`

The `api.html` file looks like this:

```
{% extends "rest_framework/base.html" %}

{% block style %}
{{ block.super }}
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/static/portal/favicon.png" />
{% endblock %}
```