# How to handle favicon request in Django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, favicon, next.js

I am coming from Node.js and I have a nextjs frontend that communicates with a Django REST API. However, each time I make a request to my Django API, the app makes an additional request:

`GET /favicon.ico`

I've tried to add favicon route in `urls.py`

```
favicon_view = RedirectView.as_view(url='/static/images/favicon.ico', permanent=True)

url(r'^favicon$',favicon_view)
```

But it doesn't works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i edit the favicon in the Browsable API in Django REST framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46842938/how-do-i-edit-the-favicon-in-the-browsable-api-in-django-rest-framework)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in the regex

```
...
url(r'^favicon\.ico$', favicon_view),
...
```

As per regex `$` indicates the end of the string so whole URL needs to put before this

Comment: What is the response you are getting for favicon request?

Answer (score -1):

you dont a view for favicon if you setup your static root in settings.py you go to your frontend and use load static tag

```
 {% load static %}
```

and in favicon link you link it

```
<link rel="icon" href="{% static 'images/favicon.png' %}" sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
```

after that you run python manage.py collectstatic

Comment: I am using the rest framework, my frontend is totally separated from my django app.