# Django Rest Framework deploy show favicon 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, django-rest-framework, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, internal-server-error

I am trying to deploy my Django rest framework to `aws eb` but when I test the API, it shows

> favicon.ico:1 GET
>   http://myapp.....com/favicon.ico
>   500 (Internal Server Error)

I update my url.py of django project to

```
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView  


 urlpatterns = [
        url('favicon.ico', RedirectView.as_view(
            url='/static/favicon/favicon.ico'))...]
```

But It still shows an internal error.

I already search and found similar questions but not a useful answer.

like that=>
[How do I edit the favicon in the browsable API in Django rest framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46842938/how-do-i-edit-the-favicon-in-the-browsable-api-in-django-rest-framework)

[how to handle favicon request in Django rest framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48604710/how-to-handle-favicon-request-in-django-rest-framework)

My API is pretty separate from the frontend so I can't change frontend for this error.

Update

If I test on local like =>

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/favicon.ico
```

it gets the same result with =>

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/
```